# Verify ubuntu 17.04 Download

Tags: software-installation

Just downloaded ubuntu 17.04. Instructions suggest verifying iso before burning. Only verification link is for 16.??.

Answer (score 2):

Please use this link to verify your download:

http://releases.ubuntu.com/17.04/

Steps to check the md5sum of `iso` file:

1. [Copy](http://releases.ubuntu.com/17.04/MD5SUMS) the md5sums for your particular download and place into a file say `check.md5`:

   ```
   echo "18cc54af55d7ca931bbb8588e8d9c1bd *ubuntu-17.04-desktop-amd64.iso" > check.md5
   ```
2. Put that file (`check.md5`) in the same folder as the downloaded `iso` file.
3. Check it with:

   ```
   md5sum -c check.md5
   ```

Comment: I Followed the link, seems it wants to down load the 1.5 MG again. I am new at this, so not sure how to proceed.

Comment: It shouldn't download any thing... which of the signature are you trying using `checksum` or `md5sums`?

Comment: First, thanks. I don't see either option, just desktop/server images, no checksum or md5sums. I am trying to create an LiveCD so I can get rid of windows vista and xp.

Comment: Please scroll down the page and you will see them. e.g. http://releases.ubuntu.com/17.04/MD5SUMS

Comment: I find four MD5SUMS files and they appear to be text pages. When I visit BurningIsoHowto, the instructions say to download md5sums to the same download directory as the iso download, and then it gives a couple of commands, but no download command. I am missing something, but just don't know what. Sorry for being so dense.

Comment: @Dennis see my updated answer

Comment: Tip: you can pipe directly to `md5sum ` (without saving to a file) according to this command line, `echo "18cc54af55d7ca931bbb8588e8d9c1bd *ubuntu-17.04-desktop-amd64.iso"|md5sum -c`

Comment: Thank you, George. Verified download, burnt CD. CD will not boot.  Checked bios, deleted disc boot, still boots to disk.  Info on CD shows it is bootable. Guess will backup data and install 17.04